# Set Database Value As Config Item Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How am I able to get the **key value** and the set it as a **config_item**. I have been trying to be able to get so can do it via form and database. I can only seem to seem to change config Item manually.

I have a form where It finds the themes and then saves the one I choose to the database.

```
Table Name Setting

setting_id = 1

group = config 

key = config_template

value = Name of theme submitted in form.
```

I would like to be able to some how use `$this->config->item('config_template')` so it will get the value.

**Because I am trying to achieve this front controller**

```
 <?php
      class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function index() {
          if(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/home.php')) {
             $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/common/home');
          } else {
             $this->load->view('default/template/common/home');
          }
        }
      }
```

**Backend Setting Controller**

```
<?php

class Setting extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('setting_model');

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
            $this->setting_model->editSetting('config', $this->input->post());
            redirect('store');
        }

        $data['action'] = site_url('setting');

        if (null !==($this->input->post('config_template'))) {
            $data['config_template'] = $this->input->post('config_template');
        } else {
            $data['config_template'] = $this->config->item('config_template');
        }

        $data['templates'] = array();

        $directories = glob(DIR_APPLICATION . 'views/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            $data['templates'][] = basename($directory);
        }
        return $this->load->view('setting/setting', $data);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a hook in your model/controller to get the values from the database and set it on run time, maybe set them in the __construct()

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //get $value from database here
    $this->config->set_item('config_template', $value);
}
```

Then in the rest of the code, you can use

```
$this->config->item('config_template')
```

To retrieve the value